# How does dynamic array memory allocation work?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

Edit: Since I've posted an improper question featuring TArray without source code I've replaced it with std::vector.

I have a dynamic array defined in main function

```
std::vector<sSymbols> arrSymbols;
```

I also have a function which add a new element to array;

```
functionOne(std::vector<TSymbols>& arrSymbolsRef)
{
    sSymbols symbolOne;
    //some symbol struct filling
    arrSymbolsRef.push_back(symbolOne);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSymbolsRef.size(); i++) 
       printf("arrSymbolsRef[%d] ptr is %d", i, &arrSymbolsRef[i]);
}
```

Updated results:
running this function in a loop would give this result:

```
arrSymbolsRef[0] ptr is -1242393600
arrSymbolsRef[0] ptr is -1257218304
arrSymbolsRef[1] ptr is -1257218244
New iteration
arrSymbolsRef[0] ptr is -1451463936
arrSymbolsRef[1] ptr is -1451463876
arrSymbolsRef[2] ptr is -1451463816
New iteration
arrSymbolsRef[0] ptr is -1450359040
arrSymbolsRef[1] ptr is -1450358980
arrSymbolsRef[2] ptr is -1450358920
arrSymbolsRef[3] ptr is -1450358860
New iteration
arrSymbolsRef[0] ptr is -1243432448
arrSymbolsRef[1] ptr is -1243432388
arrSymbolsRef[2] ptr is -1243432328
arrSymbolsRef[3] ptr is -1243432268
arrSymbolsRef[4] ptr is -1243432208
New iteration
arrSymbolsRef[0] ptr is -1243432448
arrSymbolsRef[1] ptr is -1243432388
arrSymbolsRef[2] ptr is -1243432328
arrSymbolsRef[3] ptr is -1243432268
arrSymbolsRef[4] ptr is -1243432208
arrSymbolsRef[5] ptr is -1243432148
New iteration
arrSymbolsRef[0] ptr is -1550211968
arrSymbolsRef[1] ptr is -1550211908
arrSymbolsRef[2] ptr is -1550211848
arrSymbolsRef[3] ptr is -1550211788
arrSymbolsRef[4] ptr is -1550211728
arrSymbolsRef[5] ptr is -1550211668
arrSymbolsRef[6] ptr is -1550211608
```

Why at some point addresses are shifting?

I need to create an array of pointers to these elements, and add new element(pointer) each time arrSymbols is increased.

But after few iterations pointers in array are pointing at wrong data.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the source of `TArray`, but it seems like this class automatically relocates the data it currently holds to some other location.

Comment: Your `TArray` is most likely having to relocate because it's attempting to keep items contiguous and can't do so at its old address.  In this case it is completely unsafe to store pointers to items in the array.

Comment: This question depends on what `TArray` is. Is that a class you wrote yourself? If so it would help to show the source code for it. If it is someone else's then link to documentation for it at least

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour, because `%d` says you promise to pass an `int`, not a `TSymbols*`.

Comment: By magic. This is the only honest answer I can give here. How are we supposed to know what your `TArray` is doing? Oh, wait, I have another one for you: **"By electricity"**.

Comment: I don't know about mystery class `TArray` but with a `std::vector` you can prevent the reallocation if you know how big the array is going to grow at the outset and you ask it to reserve that much space with `std::vector::reserve`.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment to the question, you can't rely on the class' storage being in the same place all the time. It will most likely have to grow as you're adding elements to it - to do that, it will allocate a new, larger block, and copy all the current data into it.

Just for the record, `std::vector` does not supply this kind of behaviour either. This simple program :

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 17 ; ++i) {
        a.push_back(i);
        std::cout << "Iteration " << i << " : "
                  << static_cast<void*>(&a[0]) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Gives the following result on my system :

```
Iteration 1 : 0x1aa9050
Iteration 2 : 0x1aa8c20
Iteration 3 : 0x1aa8c20
Iteration 4 : 0x1aa9070
Iteration 5 : 0x1aa9070
Iteration 6 : 0x1aa9070
Iteration 7 : 0x1aa9070
Iteration 8 : 0x1aa90a0
Iteration 9 : 0x1aa90a0
Iteration 10 : 0x1aa90a0
Iteration 11 : 0x1aa90a0
Iteration 12 : 0x1aa90a0
Iteration 13 : 0x1aa90a0
Iteration 14 : 0x1aa90a0
Iteration 15 : 0x1aa90a0
Iteration 16 : 0x1aa90f0
```

As you can see, the starting address of the vector's storage changes a few times. Now, since `std::vector` guarantees contiguous storage of its elements, the addresses of all its elements change as well.

I don't think there is any dynamically resizeable container that would guarantee constant addresses for its elements, unless you pre-declared the maximum amount of elements that can be stored. In this case it could just allocate one huge block at once and not reallocate ever again. If you need such behaviour, look into using something like `std::array`, or create a wrapper around `std::vector` that doesn't allow modifying its size.

Comment: `std::list` guarantees references (and by extension, pointers) to elements are never invalidated, as long as the element is not erased. If you only add and remove to the front or back, `std::deque` gives you the same guarantee. You can also use a vector of smart pointers, in which case the pointees would be safe.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley : Good point. I mentally constrained myself to containers that guarantee contiguous storage.